# Contact form email template - Array

Tags: magento-1.8, contact-us, contact-form

If I have a checkbox on the contact form how do I pull these values into the email template.

My form looks like

```
<li>
    <label for="telephone">Contact Method</label>
    <div class="input-box">
       <input type="checkbox" name="contact_method[]" value="Telephone"> Telephone<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="contact_method[]" value="Email"> Email<br>
    </div>
 </li>
```

However if I do

```
Contact Method: {{var data.contact_method}}
```

The value comes out as array

Comment: Did you try changing the name to `contact_method` instead of `contact_method[]` ?

Comment: Yes I tried {{var data.contact_method[]}} and {{var data.contact_method[0]}} but both come out blank

Comment: In your form "<input type="checkbox" name="contact_method[]" value="Telephone"> Telephone<br>" remove the [] from contact_method

Comment: If I remove the [] then only 1 option can be selected

Comment: I didn't notice you were using checkboxes. You should not be using the same name in case of checkboxes, try using two different names and then use 2 lines in your email template.

Comment: Using the same name and having an array of values is standard HTML - http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox

But are you saying Magento can cope with this?

Answer (score 2):

Magento doesn't allow to use array in email variable.So change checkbox html as below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="contact_method_tel" value="Telephone"> Telephone<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="contact_method_email" value="Email"> Email<br>
```

Now use depend condition (can also use if/else) in email template based on below checkbox selection as below.

```
{{depend data.contact_method_tel}}
    {{var data.contact_method_tel}} //show telephone if checked
{{/depend}}
{{depend data.contact_method_email}}
    {{var data.contact_method_email}} //show email if checked
{{/depend}}
```